# RuntimeException Unable to start activity.. InflateException Binary XML line #37: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView

Tags: android, exception, crash, android-actionbar, android-theme

When I add theme to activity, application crashes after opening that activity with below logcat

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.jd.activity, PID: 16672
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jd.activity/com.jd.activity.AlertActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5479)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3296)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3359)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:362)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2031)
at com.jd.activity.AlertActivity.onCreate(AlertActivity.java:59)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
... 11 more
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
... 25 more
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.initTitle(ActionBarView.java:1200)
at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.setDisplayOptions(ActionBarView.java:982)
at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>(ActionBarView.java:398)
... 28 more
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
... 37 more
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x2
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:327)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1003)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:908)
... 40 more
```

My activity tag in manifest

```
<activity
        android:name="com.jd.activity.AlertActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" >
    </activity>
```

even the app crashes after adding theme

```
 android:theme="@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle"
```

When i remove the theme line, works well.

I have added `android-support-v7-appcompat` to project's build path and that application I have imported from sdk\extras\android\v7 with 'copy projects into worksplace' ticked.

Also in manifest
 `<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />`

**My final goal is to add ActionBar. Is there any other easy way to add action bar without using theme?**

Comment: try  `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"`

Comment: hey.. it solves the crash issue with Theme.AppCompat, but I can't see ActionBar then. Plz plz tell me what theme I have to use to add ActionBar with my color and a button on ActionBar to open drawer after clicking that button

Comment: @ShirishHerwade use toolbar http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Comment: try this theme  `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    </style>` and set this theme to your activity

Comment: In the link provided by Raghunandan, there's written as "All of your Activities must extend from ActionBarActivity". Is it true??, because I'm extending Activity.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by crating my own theme

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverflowMenuButton</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/gray</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/gray</item>
    <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/ActionButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/CloseButton</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/action_bar_inset_backgruond</item>
    <item name="contentInsetLeft">10dp</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/black_tint_80</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverflowMenuButton</item>
    <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/ActionButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/CloseButton</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/action_bar_inset_backgruond</item>
    <item name="android:logo">@drawable/actionbar_space_between_icon_and_title</item>
    <item name="contentInsetLeft">10dp</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">100dp</item>
    <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/ActionButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="OverflowMenuButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_action_view_as_grid</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton">
    <item name="android:minWidth">100dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">100dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">100dip</item>                  
</style>

<style name="CloseButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.CloseMode">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ic_action_view_as_grid</item>
</style>
```

And applying that in manifest.xml

```
android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
```

And also, while doing this, there was no need to extend from `ActionBarActivity`